# Link pages from a child term to it's parent

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have really two questions in one. I have pathauto make a page for all my terms. I have something like this:

```
USA
-NY
-NJ
-LA
UK
-London
-Hogwarts
-Manchester
France
-Paris
...
```

Anyway pathauto made pages for all the terms, so I have `site/USA` , `site/USA/NY` etc. I want to make it so that `site/USA/NY` has a link to it's parent which is `site/USA`. Is there any way to do this?

Another question, I'm also using the hierarchical select plugin to make a user select the deepest child possible (in this case just one level in). When a user tags content with NY, I also want that content to be tagged with USA, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node will have relation with the child term but there is no direct relation between the node and parent term.
So i think there are two ways to do it..
**ONE** : use node api and attached the parent term with the node.
**TWO** : while displaying the node fetch the parent term of the term and show them as well.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: which way you want to do it?

Comment: The one with the least PHP programming

Comment: It would be difficult to explain in code but with taxonomy api you should call the parent term in node tpl file.